# SQL код, таблица Борей

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```sql
UPDATE Сотрудники SET Сотрудники.Обращение = "Sr"
WHERE (((Сотрудники.Должность) Like "Директор%") AND 
       ((Сотрудники.Страна)="Испания")) OR (((Сотрудники.Страна)="Мексика"));
```

вот такой вот код,  нужно проверить Содержит ли текст запросов ошибку? Если содержит, то в чем она заключается? Если запрос верный, что будет результатом выполнения запроса?
Понимаю что глупый вопрос, но если кто может, помогите

Comment: Скобки открывающие и закрывающие посчитайте и всё будет понятно

Comment: одинаковое количество ведь

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Там у Вас чехарда со скобками.
По скобкам получается так:

```
WHERE (Должность LIKE Директор AND Страна=Испания) OR Страна=Мексика
```

Т.е. Ваш запрос поставит `Sr` в `Обращение` во все "мексиканские" строчки, и лишь в те "испанские", где `должность` начинается с `Директор`

А еще, имена таблиц и полей по-русски. Не будет проблемой?

Comment: добавил таблицу сверху, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Так и что? Добавили Вы таблицу... Вопрос-то в чем? Вы спросили про ошибки - ошибок нет. Синтаксис правильный. Логика странная, но мало ли.... Что запрос делает при таком построении с такими с кобками - я Вам объяснил... Что нужно-то?